# Google Classroom character formatting (Bold, Italics, Underline) via API

Tags: google-apps-script, styling, google-classroom

While creating an Assigment in Google Classroom we can now change the format/styling of the characters in the description to:

- Bold
- Italics
- Underline
- Bullet Points

**Can character formatting be done via de API as well?**
I searched in the Google Classroom API documentation but couldnt find an answer.

[image: Google Classroom Font Styling]

Comment: Have you tried [DocumentApp.Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

Comment: Yeah, tried a few different things including the one you mention. 
I also tried the myDescriptionVariable.bold() but this only embeds the <b> tag surrounding the string but Google Classroom reads those tags as simple text so it is not generating the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is not possible at this time via the API.

If you inspect the resources in the documentation, such as https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork. There is no relevant field. Also, doing some experiments trying request some of the items and then making changes to the format, I wasn't able to find any of the fields changing.

I would suggest filling out a feature request with this template:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908

Be sure to include as much info as possible and any justification / practical use cases to ensure it gets noticed. Bear in mind that if it gains more stars (people interested in the request) then it is more likely to get attention.

---

**EDIT**:

OP made a Feature Request:

> #### [Coursework description character formatting / styling via Google Classroom API](https://issuetracker.google.com/185916479)

If you want this feature be sure to press the star icon (☆) to let Google know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created the feature request as you suggested.
In case other people are looking for the same feature, you can find my request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185916479

Comment: Good job, I'll add it as an edit to my answer for visibility